# redirecting to other page with value in javascript via click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a Javascript file to do these operations:

1. Pass the current link to the other page
2. Click on hypertext or image that is created dynamically in JavaScript file to redirect

Just I want to have a Javascript link in the html body and not other thing same this :

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JScript.js"></script>
</div>
```

And in the JavaScript file I have these:

```
var DivTag = document.createElement("Div");
DivTag.setAttribute('ID', 'MyDivTagID');
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("$MyDivTagID").click(function(e) {
            window.location = "http://www.MyLink.com/?Url=" + window.location;
    });
});
```

This is not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues

1. you never added the div to the page
2. you used $ instead of # to access the div by ID
3. you do not consistently use jQuery

Plain JS: [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/fqtVU/)

```
 window.onload=function () {
   var DivTag = document.createElement("div");
   DivTag.setAttribute('id', 'MyDivTagID');
   DivTag.innerHTML="Click";
   DivTag.onclick = function(e) {
     window.location = "http://www.MyLink.com/?Url=" + escape(window.location.href);
   }
   document.body.appendChild(DivTag);
 }
```

Using linked image:

```
 window.onload=function () {
   var DivTag = document.createElement("div");
   DivTag.setAttribute('id', 'MyDivTagID');
   var anchor = document.createElement("a");
   anchor.href="#";
   anchor.onclick = function(e) {
     window.location = "http://www.MyLink.com/?Url=" + escape(window.location.href);
   }
   var img = document.createElement("img");
   img.src="image.gif";
   img.style.border="0";
   anchor.appendChild(img);
   DivTag.appendChild(anchor);
   document.body.appendChild(DivTag);
 }
```

jQuery: [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/AkdUk/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').append('<div id="MyDivTagID">Click</div>');
  $("#MyDivTagID").click(function(e) {
    window.location = "http://www.MyLink.com/?Url=" + escape(window.location.href);
  });
});
```

Comment: how can I use image for link in java script version ?

Comment: I use This code for changing cursor : img.style.cursor = "hand"; but in firefox it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

A small change to the jQuery code from mplungjan:

Change:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').append('<div id="MyDivTagID">Click</div>').click(function(e) {
    window.location = "http://www.MyLink.com/?Url=" + escape(window.location.href);
  });
});
```

To:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').append('<div id="MyDivTagID">Click</div>').find('#MyDivTagID').click(function(e) {
    window.location = "http://www.MyLink.com/?Url=" + escape(window.location.href);
  });
});
```

If you output `e.currentTarget` from the anonymous click handler function you get `body` since the event handler was attached to the `body` in mplungjan's solution. All I did was add `.find('#MyDivTagID')` directly after the `.append()` function so the click handler gets attached to the `div` and not the `body`.